# Нужно что бы пользователя спрашивало, нужно ли дешифровать или оставить просто шифровку

Tags: python

```
import socket
import threading
import cezar

nickname = input("Choose your nickname : ").strip()
while not nickname:
    nickname = input("Your nickname should not be empty : ").strip()
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "192.168.2.107"
port = 4444
my_socket.connect((host, port))


def thread_sending():
    while True:
        message_to_send = input()
        if message_to_send:
            message_with_nickname = nickname + " : " + message_to_send
            cezar.myencode(message_with_nickname)                       #шифр 
            my_socket.send(message_with_nickname.encode())

def thread_receiving():
    while True:
        message = my_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        cezar.mydecode(message)                     #дешифр
        print(message)


thread_send = threading.Thread(target=thread_sending)
thread_receive = threading.Thread(target=thread_receiving)
thread_send.start()
thread_receive.start()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала спрашиваешь:
`use_cezar = int(input('Использовать? (0/1):'))`
А дальше в коде проверяешь через if/else; 0 - False (нет), 1 - True (да).